AD dropping LDAPS connections not from localhost
I'm working with two AD servers in a domain. We also have Keycloak as SSO for all our internet stuff.
We'd like if users could actually change their password via Keycloak, but AD does NOT like it if that happens via an unencrypted connection for obvious reasons.
Now, we have LDAPS working, to a degree - I can connect to it with LDP via localhost. But the external IP (10.170.0.2) does not work. AND NEITHER DOES 127.0.0.1??? THE FUCK IS GOING ON HERE? Looking at netstat -an, I see an open connection on 0.0.0.0:636

So, it turns out that because of the certificate, requests that don't go to the actual domain (e.g. dc01.contoso.com) that the cert is certifying, LDAPS connection requests just get dropped.
Seemingly, localhost as a hostname is the only exception to it, probably because it gets resolved to the hostname, and not the IP of the domain controller.
